# How to work around needing to access context state within the entry point of my App before the Provider has been defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a react native app. I have a hook `useAppIsReady` that contains a check for whether images have been loaded yet located in my `App.tsx`.

The way it works is I have state in my context `numberOfImagesLoaded`. I have multiple images loaded within Home. When an image loads, `numberOfImagesLoaded` gets incremented by 1, and once it reaches a specified number, `appIsReady` gets set to true.

The problem is that I can't use `useAppIsReady` within my `App.tsx` since `numberOfImagesLoaded` is located within my context, and `useAppIsReady` is used within `App.tsx`, the entry point to my application, so the return statement that contains my whole app wrapped in context is defined after `useAppIsReady` gets called. So I'm forced to place `useAppIsReady` inside a child component `Home` instead, which is suboptimal. How can I make `useAppIsReady` work in my app's entry point, `App.tsx`?

(btw I don't want to define the `numberOfImagesLoaded` state in my `App.tsx` because it will be a pain to pass down through props)

useAppIsReady

```js
const useAppIsReady = () => {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  // If all images are loaded

  const imagesAreLoaded = context.numberOfImagesLoaded > 5;

  if (imagesAreLoaded && !appIsReady) {
    setAppIsReady(true);
  }

  return appIsReady;
};
```

App.tsx

```js
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {

  // useAppIsReady() won't work since context has not yet been defined

  const appIsReady = useAppIsReady();

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<AppParamList>();

   useEffect(() => {
    const prepare = async () => {
      if (appIsReady) {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      }
    };

    prepare();
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <AppProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Tab.Navigator
          >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Tab.Screen
              name="MyQueues"
              component={MyQueuesScreen}
            />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AppProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just don't use context. Load images in App.